# Is there a name for this type of double speak?

Tags: indirect-speech, indirect-question

My colleague will indirectly ask me to do something by using a statement Eg. John needs a form = can you print me a form to fill out on behalf of John. Her tone of voice does not indicate it's a request but she stares waiting for me to do it.  I need to put a name to this annoyance.  Thanks!

Edit: I am ideally looking for a pejorative adjective as a name/definition.

Here is another example:
"We've ran out of microbrushes in here" = Please can you get me some more microbrushes
A small request but the statements are quite abrupt and used instead of a question.

Here is another non workplace example:
Someone may say "This man has just collapsed" but everyone takes this statement as a direction to help the man Eg. "Please help this man he has collapsed"

(This is my first time using this app thank you for everyone's patience!)

Comment: She could be Russian, I'm not kidding. Russians tend to be very matter-of-fact. *Diplomacy*, *run-of-the-mill politeness* (for want of a better word) and *tact* are practically foreign concepts.

Comment: I am currently attempting to teach myself Russian as a new years resolution and I know exactly what you mean with their sentence structures! Sadly she is not Russian

Comment: Pejorative if there is one! And an adjective too, but I am open to all answers if I'm honest. @mari-lou A

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your help! I have just edited the post now (I am very new to this website)

Comment: If you are an employee whose job includes such supportive tasks, then it is unreasonable to expect each direction from management to be in the form of a polite request. I'm also wondering if you would be as annoyed were it a man rather than a woman expecting you to do your job.

Comment: I see that someone has voted to close. This means your question is at risk of being placed on hold. Add a little more detail **AND** a sample sentence. E.g. "Whenever my colleague asks for something I always feel her tone of voice is _____"

Comment: @KarlG Apologies for my example, it is not my strongest one, I work in a dental practice so quite often the situation wouldn't make as much sense in an example.  I will add another example to my post.  Also her gender is not a deciding factor, it's her behaviour, accompanied with other issues (such as saying yes to everything without checking it is correct first)

Comment: @NigelJ The examples are in the workplace as those are the ones I have experienced. I am looking for a term to call that type of behaviour, using my real life experiences as examples. This is my first ever time using this type of website and decided to use it after seeing a very similar question answered when I was looking for the term myself. Sorry if I have used this website incorrectly

Comment: It depends on who you're going to share this word with...if it's with the offender, I'd go for something that's carefully couched with respectful deference, such as "Milly, would you mind *asking* me for something in the future?  I'm not always clear that your statements are actually requests.  Thanks!"  Or if it's to bitch about her to your friends, I might say, "Milly comes off as the high, supreme ruler of the universe who's every utterance must be taken as a command!" Good luck with that! :-)

Comment: Another thought is that if your colleague expects these tasks to be done automatically by you and for some reason, you're not doing them or possibly not getting them done in a timely enough fashion, her tone of voice might actually be "pique" or "annoyance" with you.  In other words, she's got an attitude and her method of communication (stating a need and expecting you to fulfill it) is her way to convey her annoyance with the situation.

Comment: @KristinaLopez in all circumstances it's jobs she should do but is using me as a method to do the boring trivial jobs (if that makes sense) I have a good non workplace example, I will add it to my original post now

Comment: In that case, I'd say she is acting "bossy".  Bossy is defined by Google as: "fond of giving people orders; domineering. Synonyms: domineering, pushy, overbearing, imperious, officious, high-handed, authoritarian, dictatorial, controlling"

Comment: @KristinaLopez what about if the situation is not a negative one? Maybe like a person mentioning "I love red dresses" hoping their partner will take that as "Please buy me a red dress" I haven't worded my question very well haha!

Comment: I think @Kristina has come up with the best word - "bossy". More formally I'd say she had an "imperious" manner. However, contrary to what you say I note that her requests are posed as questions, and in one instance you do quote her as saying "please". However I am aware that even the most technically polite language can come across as offensive and overbearing if the tone is not right.

Comment: In your non-workplace example, you can only assume that the person saying "This man has collapsed" is actually asking for someone to do something.  I think there's an assumption that someone will do something but I'd call this behavior differently than the workplace example.  In this case, the person is hoping someone will help but is not actually asking for help due to panic? shock? too shy to ask something of strangers?  They're actually quite different situations, IMO.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spanish there is a grammatical concept, called an **indirect command**, for statements that are:

> *["a wish or hope that something will happen or that someone will do something"](https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verb/indirectcommands.html)*

While English doesn't have a specific syntax for an indirect command (most of this would be communicated through inflection or body language), I'd argue that the same definition for the Spanish concept works here.

If you are looking for an adjective that describes this behavior, I'd use **bumptious**.

> *["presumptuously, obtusely, and often noisily self-assertive"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bumptious)*

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much